# How do I reduce the possibilities in Mastermind based on feedback?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

I am following Donald Knuth's algorithm to solve the game [Mastermind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mastermind_%28board_game%29).

However, I am stuck on step two:

> 1. Create a set S of remaining possibilities (at this point there are
>    1296). The first guess is aabb.
> 2. Remove all possibilities from S that
>    would not give the same score of colored and white pegs if they were
>    the answer.
> 3. For each possible guess (not necessarily in S) calculate
>    how many possibilities from S would be eliminated for each possible
>    colored/white score. The score of the guess is the least of such
>    values. Play the guess with the highest score (minimax).
> 4. Go back to
>    step 2 until you have got it right.

I generate the set of possibilities (basically 6 x 6 x 6  x 6). From here, I formulate the initial guess of `aabb`. The "mastermind" gives feedback in the form of *x* white pegs and *y* black pegs.

The white pegs indicate one of the four colors in our guess was correct but in the wrong location. The black pegs indicate that one of the four colors in our guess was correct *and* in the correct location.

From here the next guess has to be modified based on that information.

My question is: Given that my first guess is `aabb` and my feedback is, say `1w1b`, what permutations do I remove from the set of possibilities?

Comment: Do you want us to list them, or describe the set?

Comment: Or just the general pattern of how you would go about getting them.

Comment: The general pattern? Not the permutations to remove for this particular case? Do you want an algorithm or what?

Comment: @Beta, I think OP wants an algorithm

Comment: Then you're not asking step 2 (evaluating our guess), it's step 3 (create new guess)

Comment: @justhalf Sorry, I removed my comments because they were wrong. Both of your answers make sense now. I didn't realize we compare the possibility to the current guess.

Comment: I have tried implementing this algorithm, but it's very slow, haha. Using random guess and possibility removal seems to work faster (although not the smallest step) on general case. It can guess 6 colors 5 pegs in under 8 guesses. Or step 3 can be changed to just consider the possibility in `S` instead of everything. See my code here: http://ideone.com/CVU0oL

Comment: When you say slow do you mean your program takes a long time to run or that it takes a lot of guesses? This algorithm should always terminate in 5 guesses or fewer.

Comment: Takes a long time to run. That's why I said using random guess is "faster although not [in] the smallest step[(guess)]".

Comment: @justhalf I'm a bit curious why it's so slow - if I finish this up I'll post a link with the speed of the program.

Comment: Because it needs to use every possible combinations (6^5 * 7C2) as a guess, and count the possibility reduce, which makes the algorithm to consider all the remaining possibilities (on the first step, this is 6^5 also). So the number of operations is in the order of 6^10, which is 60,466,176. That's huge!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def CalcScore(answer, solution):
    """ A function that will return a tupple of the number of white & black pegs """
    ...

todel = []
for poss in poss_answers:  # Assuming that poss_answers is a list/array of possible ansers
    if not current_score == CalcScore(ThisTry, poss):
       todel.append(poss)
for delthis in todel:
    poss_answers.remove(delthis)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's actually quite clear in the step 2. Here is the explained version.

You can go through each permutation, computes its score (like `3w`, `1w3b`, etc) with respect to the current guess, and removes those permutation which give different score that the actual score.